# Return type deduction with multi-statement lambdas

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, g++, trailing-return-type

I've been writing code, and I've recently found out that g++ doesn't warn me about a certain class of issue: per C++11 5.1.2.4, if your lambda is not a single return statement then the return type must be declared as a trailing-return-type or be void.

Although g++ is allowed to compile invalid code if it makes enough sense, is there a way to either turn this behavior off (allowed with `-fpedantic` in g++-4.7) or all least warn about it?

Example code:

```
[]() { return 0; } //is fine
[&a]() { a++; return 0; } //is not fine but g++ doesn't warn me
[&a]() -> int {a++; return 0; } //is fine again
```

C++11 5.1.2.4

> An implementation shall not add members of rvalue reference type to the closure type.
>   If a lambda-expression does not include a lambda-declarator, it is as if the lambda-declarator were (). If a lambda-expression does not include a trailing-return-type, it is as if the trailing-return-type denotes the following type:
>
> — if the compound-statement is of the form
>   { attribute-specifier-seq(opt) return expression ; }
>   the type of the returned expression after lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1), array-to-pointer conversion (4.2), and function-to-pointer conversion (4.3);
>
> — otherwise, void.

Comment: +1 I noticed that, but I never thought to try to fix it.

Comment: Isn't this an extension, it's deducing the return as if there were only one statement, and they anticipate this will be standardized?

Comment: @Potatoswatter, In that case, it warns on VLAs, so why not this?

Comment: clang 3.2 and VS2012 also accepts the code.

Comment: @Csq, the code is accepted, that's fine.  Compilers are allowed to accept any code they like.  I actually found out about this because clang (3.1) was nice enough to give me a warning about it.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity Compilers are required to reject code that violates any "shall", etc in the standard.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity clang 3.2 doesn't seem to give a warning even with pedantic - [link](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3G3E5y$2)

Comment: What does it mean "if a lambda-expression does not include a lambda-declarator, it is as if the lambda-declarator were()"?

Comment: It means that if you have no arguments you can declare your lambda like this: `[]{return 0;}`

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity oh, I thought that's what it meant but I tried it and it didn't compile. But it turns out I just forgot the double semicolon :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is because it is a defect in the standard, and will be changed (see [DR 975](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#975)):

> 975 Restrictions on return type deduction for lambdas
>
> There does not appear to be any technical difficulty that would
>   require the current restriction that the return type of a lambda can
>   be deduced only if the body of the lambda consists of a single return
>   statement. In particular, multiple return statements could be
>   permitted if they all return the same type.

I doubt if there is a way to turn it off.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity: I updated the link again. It looks like it has been returned to "review" status from "ready" for more discussion, but I highly doubt it will be rejected. Also, the submitter of the proposal, is also the implementer of it in gcc, so I doubt there is anyway to change the behavior in gcc.

Comment: Indeed, as of C++14 this restriction is lifted.

Answer (score 1):

GCC 4.8.1 (and possibly earlier) and clang 3.3 already implements it; fixing DR975.

There is now a proposal (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3386.html) to get it into C++1y