# Strange undefined behaviour with tricky lambda expression

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, functional-programming

I've been struggling against a problem with lambda expressions that was jeopardizing a project of mine. I have found a solution, but I would like to understand exactly how and why it works, and if it is reliable.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <unordered_map>

typedef std::function<const int&(const int&)> Callback;

int f(int i, Callback callback) {
    if (i <= 2) return 1;
    return callback(i-1) + callback(i-2);
}

int main(void) {

    std::unordered_map<int, int> values;

    Callback callback = [&](const int& i) {
        if (values.find(i) == values.end()) {
            int v = f(i, callback);
            values.emplace(i, v);
        }
        return values.at(i);
    };

    std::cout << f(20, callback) << std::endl;

    return 0;

}
```

I know this is a crazy way to compute the 20th Fibonacci number, but it is the most compact SSCCE I was able to elaborate.

If I compile the code above with `g++ -O0` and I execute the program, I get `6765`, which is actually the 20th Fibonacci number. If I compile with `-O1`, `-O2` or `-O3` I get `262144`, which is rubbish.

If I profile the program with Valgrind (compiling with `-O0 -g`), I get `Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)` on the line `std::cout << f(20, callback) << std::endl;` but the stack trace doesn't say anything useful.

I don't know why I ended up with this:

```
Callback callback = [&](const int& i) -> const int& {
```

With this little modification, everything works as expected compiling with any optimization level, and Valgrind reports no issues.

Can you help me understand what's going on?

Comment: just out of curiosity does the program work without `&` s

Comment: Is that lambda legal C++11?  Ie, did they slip multi-line return type deduction in while I wasn't looking?

Comment: @Yakk g++ at least has support for C++1y return type deduction, [it seems to have leaked into -std=c++11](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=ad30330709f5545cb36641461a60f3ba-c944ac6b0eed3bfc48b1f78a894f6965). We'll call it a "conforming extension" ;)

Comment: @Casey - formally, you can call it a conforming extension if the compiler issues a diagnostic.

Comment: Extension? So if the lambda is multi-line the deduction is not allowed (or considered) by the standard?

Comment: @gd1 Yes, C++11 only allows return type deduction for lambdas whose body is a single return statement (§5.1.2/4).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Without the `-> const int&` the return type of the lambda is `int`. Since the return type of `Callback` is `const int&`, `callback` ends up returning a reference to the temporary it uses to hold the return value of the lambda expression. Undefined behavior.

For this simple example, the easy fix is to not use references at all ([Example at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=ad30330709f5545cb36641461a60f3ba-c944ac6b0eed3bfc48b1f78a894f6965)), but I assume your real code is handling more heavyweight objects than `int`. It's unfortunate that `std::function` isn't specified to warn when you assign a function that returns a non-reference to a `std::function` whose return type *is* a reference.

Comment: I thought that the compiler could infer the actual return type from the `Callback` type, also matching with the fact that `std::unordered_map::at(...)` returns a reference. *Or at least refuse to compile with an error*. Thank you! EDIT: yes, objects are not `int`s.

Comment: The return type deduction works just like `auto` and template function argument deduction, i.e., when you feed it a `T&` it deduces to `T`.

Comment: In fact I am forced to use `auto&`, but in the lambda "signature" I cannot use `-> &`, somehow.

Comment: @gd1 `-> decltype(auto)` will deduce `int&` for this lambda in C++14, not sure if it's implemented in g++ yet.

Answer (score 3):

[Casey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/923854/casey)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18276826/1137388) is spot on. I would just like to add something. (It seens that adding on top of Casey's good answers is becoming a common behavior of mine ;-).) Actually, my remark is on [gd1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/671092/gd1)'s comment on [Casey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/923854/casey)'s [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18276826/1137388).

I guess the OP is using `g++ -std=c++1y` because, in C++11, the returned type of the lambda shown there is set to `void`. Indeed, the compiler deduces the returned type only if the lambda's body contains a single `return` statement. Otherwise, the compiler assumes this type is `void`. In C++14 automatic deduction for returned type (not only for lambdas but also for functions) is more powerful .

As one can see [n3582](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3582.html) -- the paper which was approved for C++14 and for which `gcc`'s implementation is a reference -- states that

> > plain auto never deduces to a reference, [...]

In the OP's example the returned type is `int` (not `const int&`). I believe one can use `-> decltype(auto)` to have the automatic deduction yielding a reference.

Comment: Thank you for this information. However I'm using `--std=c++11`.

Comment: @CassioNeri, This is incorrect.  Although the standard specifies the behavior you're describing, GCC permits it and will auto deduce the correct return type.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14450608/return-type-deduction-with-multi-statement-lambdas for more information.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity: I see (thanks for the reference), even without `-std=c++1y` GCC accepts the OP's lambda. Nevertheless, logically speaking, this doesn't imply that gd1 is not using `-std=c++1y` and, consequently, that my *guess* was wrong. However, his/her comment above does imply that. ;-)